# What is the best way to find and replace all elements with a certain colour using Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that is intended to be white-labelled by the user based on the colour they want. I had specifically picked the colour #E2122F for everything that needs to be white-labelled and figured that I could probably write some script to either scan the document's stylesheet or the page to find and change/overwrite any instance of "#E2122F" to whatever the user wants it to be. Is this possible?

So far, I've tried using this code:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var colour = "RGB(226, 18, 47)";
var userColour = "#ff9343";
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].style.color = colour) {
    elements[i].style.color = userColour;
  }
}
```

This seems to change the CSS for all the other elements that DON'T have the `colour` value. I've tried using `.filter` as well with no luck.

What would be the best way to achieve what I'm looking for?

To clarify, here's some dummy HTML and CSS:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var colour = "#F44";
var userColour = "#FF1";

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].style.color == colour) {
    elements[i].style.color = userColour;
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  color: #F44;
}

.button {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.button.primary {
  background-color: #F44;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>This text should be black <a href="#">but this text should be red</a></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda molestiae corporis <a href="#">nesciunt ut quis, explicabo quasi similique</a> amet vitae dolores voluptatem voluptates quos eos tempora dolor possimus recusandae rem omnis! Ea, <a href="#">adipisci veniam?</a>  Aliquid corrupti assumenda nulla aperiam, facilis fuga.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda molestiae corporis <a href="#">nesciunt ut quis, explicabo quasi similique</a> amet vitae dolores voluptatem voluptates quos eos tempora dolor possimus recusandae rem omnis! Ea, <a href="#">adipisci veniam?</a>  Aliquid corrupti assumenda nulla aperiam, facilis fuga.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda molestiae corporis <a href="#">nesciunt ut quis, explicabo quasi similique</a> amet vitae dolores voluptatem voluptates quos eos tempora dolor possimus recusandae rem omnis! Ea, <a href="#">adipisci veniam?</a>  Aliquid corrupti assumenda nulla aperiam, facilis fuga.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda molestiae corporis <a href="#">nesciunt ut quis, explicabo quasi similique</a> amet vitae dolores voluptatem voluptates quos eos tempora dolor possimus recusandae rem omnis! Ea, <a href="#">adipisci veniam?</a>  Aliquid corrupti assumenda nulla aperiam, facilis fuga.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda molestiae corporis <a href="#">nesciunt ut quis, explicabo quasi similique</a> amet vitae dolores voluptatem voluptates quos eos tempora dolor possimus recusandae rem omnis! Ea, <a href="#">adipisci veniam?</a>  Aliquid corrupti assumenda nulla aperiam, facilis fuga.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda molestiae corporis <a href="#">nesciunt ut quis, explicabo quasi similique</a> amet vitae dolores voluptatem voluptates quos eos tempora dolor possimus recusandae rem omnis! Ea, <a href="#">adipisci veniam?</a>  Aliquid corrupti assumenda nulla aperiam, facilis fuga.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda molestiae corporis <a href="#">nesciunt ut quis, explicabo quasi similique</a> amet vitae dolores voluptatem voluptates quos eos tempora dolor possimus recusandae rem omnis! Ea, <a href="#">adipisci veniam?</a>  Aliquid corrupti assumenda nulla aperiam, facilis fuga.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda molestiae corporis <a href="#">nesciunt ut quis, explicabo quasi similique</a> amet vitae dolores voluptatem voluptates quos eos tempora dolor possimus recusandae rem omnis! Ea, <a href="#">adipisci veniam?</a>  Aliquid corrupti assumenda nulla aperiam, facilis fuga.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda molestiae corporis <a href="#">nesciunt ut quis, explicabo quasi similique</a> amet vitae dolores voluptatem voluptates quos eos tempora dolor possimus recusandae rem omnis! Ea, <a href="#">adipisci veniam?</a>  Aliquid corrupti assumenda nulla aperiam, facilis fuga.</p>

<div class="button primary">Submit</div>
```

Comment: You made a typo. Your `if` statement contains an **assignment** instead of a **comparison**. (Also you didn't include any HTML. You should provide a [mcve] using the live demo feature of the question editor.)

Comment: In the if statement, change `=` into `==`. Using one `=`, you are assigning the value. What you want to achieve is to compare the two values.

Comment: @Quentin just included some more code in the OP. Apologies. I'm still getting used to using SO.

Comment: Good work with the example but could you please replace all `#E2122F` (etc) with simpler colors such as red (#FF0000), blue (#0000FF) etc. Right now your example code seems to work as-is.

Comment: @SalmanA - done, though it doesn't seem to work (for me at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to keep in mind:

1. Do not compare a color value with something like `#FF0000` or `red` or `chucknorris`. Compare them with [resolved values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolved_value) e.g. `rgb(255, 0, 0)`.
2. Do not use `elem.style.color` as it will simply return the color defined inside the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) attribute.

It would be best to use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to test the actual color applied on the element:

```js
var tests = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  console.log(tests[i]);
  console.log("elem.style.color = " + tests[i].style.color);
  console.log("getComputedStyle(elem).color = " + getComputedStyle(tests[i]).color);
}
```

```css
.redtext {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<div class="test" style="color: #FF0000;">Test</div>
<div class="test" style="color: #F00;">Test</div>
<div class="test" style="color: red;">Test</div>
<div class="test redtext">Test</div>
```

Having said that, if the color is embedded inside a stylesheet (and the stylesheet is embedded or hosted on same domain) then it would be best that you alter the stylesheet:

```js
[...document.styleSheets].forEach(function(styleSheet) {
  var cssRules;
  try {
    cssRules = styleSheet.cssRules;
  } catch (e) {
    // most probably a cross-origin stylesheet
    return;
  }
  [...cssRules].forEach(function(cssRule) {
    if (cssRule instanceof CSSStyleRule && cssRule.style.color === "rgb(255, 68, 68)") {
      cssRule.style.color = "#008000";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #F44;
}

.wlabel {
  color: #F44;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
}

.button.primary {
  background-color: #F44;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>This text should be black <a href="#">but this text should be green</a></p>
<p>This text should be black <span class="wlabel">but this text should be green</span></p>
<div class="button primary">Submit</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the issue beautifully. The stylesheet solution was exactly what I was looking for!